# How to pass time_select in controller params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, time, parameters

```
<%= f.time_select :exact,  {ampm: true, :discard_minute=> true} %> # t.time     "exact"
```

How do I pass the above in params?

```
session[:challenge_exact] = params[:exact].parse_time_select! # got nil error
session[:challenge_exact] = challenge_params[:exact]
session[:challenge_exact] = [params["challenge"]["exact(1i)"], params["challenge"]["exact(2i)"], params["challenge"]["exact(3i)"], params["challenge"]["exact(4i)"], params["challenge"]["exact(5i)"]].join(',')
```

None of the above work. After the challenge is created I see that `exact: nil` even though it was populated in the form.

```
Started POST "/challenges" for ::1 at 2017-05-02 08:28:31 -0400
Processing by ChallengesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"oN+DzJK+/GGmpTOOVYMUJQdywuENwxhmX/EVeW6NSZ3w1MctoMd/VHS39d+JasEjHujO88nLPSB2qUKEhet5yA==", "challenge"=>{"name"=>"Write 3 Gratitudes", "categorization"=>"health", "category"=>"goal", "deadline(2i)"=>"6", "deadline(3i)"=>"2", "deadline(1i)"=>"2017", "push"=>"0", "message"=>"1", "mail"=>"0", "remind"=>["mon", "thu", ""], "exact(1i)"=>"2017", "exact(2i)"=>"5", "exact(3i)"=>"2", "exact(4i)"=>"08", "exact(5i)"=>"27", "conceal"=>"0"}, "number"=>"", "email"=>"", "button"=>""}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/signup
Completed 302 Found in 47ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

After POST challenge a person then creates a user account...

```
    Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2017-05-03 01:02:13 -0400
    Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4Lv5NSfH9tMnC9+t5bVC5x1d571y0jhwsgvYU3t2sp85XAnNOsHk+FCmtGcj2wJVysV6IlAIzF4jCx1hIofwsNg==", "user"=>{"name"=>"test", "last_name"=>"daddy", "email"=>"testdaddy@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "time_zone"=>"Eastern Time (US & Canada)", "subscribe"=>"0"}, "button"=>""}
       (0.2ms)  BEGIN
      User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('testdaddy@gmail.com') LIMIT 1
      SQL (2.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("time_zone", "name", "last_name", "subscribe", "email", "password_digest", "number", "created_at", "updated_at", "activation_digest", "activated") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11) RETURNING "id"  [["time_zone", "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"], ["name", "test"], ["last_name", "daddy"], ["subscribe", "f"], ["email", "testdaddy@gmail.com"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$JSSPUl0JDnUXybnAuSnEO.q5DgZscaU3hRpcM4C5L0a0aEtflzb7ne"], ["number", "15169499507"], ["created_at", "2017-05-03 05:02:14.144232"], ["updated_at", "2017-05-03 05:02:14.144232"], ["activation_digest", "$2a$10$NDtWKvxuJm/Hb9YIOzuVIuPpttCZwjsgYws6HhEcbHc.PukxXNpeLa"], ["activated", "t"]]
       (18.8ms)  COMMIT
       (0.2ms)  BEGIN
      User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 16]]
# AS YOU CAN SEE WITH INSERT INTO CHALLENGES FOR SOME REASON THE SESSION PARAMS FOR EXACT ISN'T PASSING FOR EXACT
      SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "challenges" ("committed", "name", "categorization", "category", "deadline", "remind", "message", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id"  [["committed", nil], ["name", "Write 3 Gratitudes"], ["categorization", "health"], ["category", "goal"], ["deadline", "2017-06-03"], ["remind", "---\n- mon\n- thu\n- ''\n"], ["message", "t"], ["user_id", 16], ["created_at", "2017-05-03 05:02:14.434251"], ["updated_at", "2017-05-03 05:02:14.434251"]]
      ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)  [["taggable_id", 40], ["taggable_type", "Challenge"]]
      ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND
                                        taggings.tagger_id = 16 AND
                                        taggings.tagger_type = 'User')  [["taggable_id", 40], ["taggable_type", "Challenge"]]
       (17.2ms)  COMMIT
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
```

How it appears in console...

```
exact: 2000-01-01 02:32:00 UTC>
```

Comment: can you paste output of `params` ?

Comment: sorry @GaganGami forgot to do that.

Comment: Did you whitelist `exact` as part of strong parameters in the controller, if your are using Rails version >= 4. Could you add that code to the question.

Comment: Yes I did @Kranti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `exact` params like:

```
> params[:challenge]["exact(1i)"]
#=> "2017"
> params[:challenge]["exact(2i)"]
#=> "5"
> params[:challenge]["exact(3i)"]
#=> "2"
> params[:challenge]["exact(4i)"]
#=> "08"
> params[:challenge]["exact(5i)"]
#=> "27"
```

You can parse time like this:

```
exact_time = "#{params[:challenge]['exact(4i)']}:#{params[:challenge]['exact(5i)']}"
#=> "08:27"
> session[:challenge_exact] = Time.parse(exact_time)
#=> 2017-05-03 08:27:00 +0530
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
session[:challenge_exact] = components_to_absolute(params[:exact])

def components_to_absolute(components)
  DateTime.new(components['exact(1i)'].to_i,
               components['exact(2i)'].to_i,
               components['exact(3i)'].to_i,
               components['exact(4i)'].to_i,
               components['exact(5i)'].to_i)
end
```